# LibGit2Sharp Cloning from a network file share

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm having issues cloning using the file transport when the remote is hosted on a network drive.

I downloaded the project and tried adding some test cases:

```
[Fact]
public void CanCloneALocalRepositoryFromANetworkDriveUri()
{
    var networkPath = @"file:///192.168.1.1/Share/TestRepo.git";
    var uri = new Uri(networkPath);
    AssertLocalClone(uri.AbsoluteUri, BareTestRepoPath);
}
```

That fails with:

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException : failed to resolve path 'file://192.168.1.1/Share/TestRepo.git': The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I tried mapping a drive letter (Z:) to the share, and ran this:

```
[Fact]
public void CanCloneALocalRepositoryFromAMappedNetworkDrive()
{
    var networkPath = @"file:///Z:/TestRepo.git";
    var uri = new Uri(networkPath);
    AssertLocalClone(uri.AbsoluteUri, BareTestRepoPath);
}
```

That fails with:

```
LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException : failed to resolve path 'Z:/TestRepo.git': The system cannot find the path specified.
```

unless I set:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLinkedConnections

to a DWORD value of 1, as per [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) - in which case the clone succeeds. However, this is not a viable solution in my situation, as it raises deployment issues in security-conscious environments.

It appears that LibGit2Sharp is not capable of cloning from a file UNC. Have I understood correctly, and if so is there any way to work around this?

Comment: 1) It might help if you shared the guts of your test helper with us. 2) Is there any difference if you use backslashes instead of forward slashes?

Comment: Happy to post it, but its just the existing suite from LibGit2Sharp. I tried many combinations of forward and backslashes, all gave the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The `file:///` URL syntax is not appropriate for UNC paths.  Just use a UNC path, eg:

```
\\192.168.1.1\Share\TestRepo.git
```

This works in LibGit2Sharp and the git command-line client as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I still can't get this to work. I changed my first test case to: `\\192.168.1.1\Share\TestRepo.git`, and get `LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException : failed to resolve path 'file://192.168.1.1/Share/TestRepo.git': The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`.

Comment: I looked in the CloneFixture test class and found the tests for file system cloning (`CanCloneALocalRepositoryFromALocalUri` and `CanCloneALocalRepositoryFromAStandardPath`) but couldn't find any for cloning from a non-local drive. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Hmm.  Let me take a look, it's possible that something regressed here.